# How to import local module golang?

Tags: go, go-modules

How can I import locally build go module?

Importing without version gives:

```
go: errors parsing go.mod:
.../go.mod:4: usage: require module/path v1.2.3
```

In the list of modules via command:

```
go list -m all
```

I see it goes without version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `replace` feature:

```
replace bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy v0.0.0-fff-zzz => ../yyy/
```